# Can I render a htmltextwriter string(with razor) into a view but keeping this as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to compile a string with some razor tags into another string with all those razor tags compiled, I see that it can be created a string from a (physical or virtual-cache) view, but there is a way to omit that and do not build the view(physical or virtual-cache), but compile the string itself in order to be a output in a controller.

I read some examples like this [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String#Feedback) but needs a view on a folder. Not what I'm looking.

i.e:

```
string htmlRazor = RenderView(stringToRender, Model);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example with expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Swati I've just edited the question with what i expect for this.